# Query Between Two Tables Using Ruby

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

My code is this

```
contact = UserContact.find(:all,:select=>"distinct app_id,number",:conditions=>"number ='1234'")

arr=[]
contact.each do|c|
 arr << c.app_id
end
name=User.find(:all,:conditions=>"id in(#{arr.join(',')}")
```

I takes two much time Can i do this using join

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do smth like this

```
User.find(:all, :joins => :user_contacts, :conditions => "user_contacts.number = '1234'")
```

user should have association. In user.rb should be:

```
has_many :user_contacts, :foreign_key => :app_id
```

But it is bad style to name column "app_id" it should be "user_id"(convention over configuration). Renamed it. After rename you can remove ", :foreign_key => :app_id"

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can NOT do "includes" and "select" in the same Active record Query.  So this will not work...

```
contacts = UserContact.includes(:users).where("number = ?", '1234').select(:app_id, :number).uniq
```

BUT.

FIRST: app_id looks like it should be called "user_id"

SECOND: What version of Rails are you using?  You might want to use the "pluck" method if you are using rails 3.2.  Hence

```
user_ids = UserContact.where("number = ?", '1234').pluck(:app_id).uniq
users = User.where(:id => user_ids)
```

THIRD: in ruby instead of doing this:

```
arr=[]
contact.each do|c|
  arr << c.app_id
end
```

do this:

```
arr = contact.inject([]) {|arr, c| arr << c.app_id}
```

FOURTH:  As in all my examples your syntax is mostly Rails 2.  I assume you are using rails 2?  If so you might need to upgrade.

FIFTH: use plural variable names if you return more than one object.  Hence

```
 contact = UserContact.....
 name=User.....
```

should be

```
 contacts = UserContact.find.....
 users = User.find.....
```

LAST:

```
  User.joins(:user_contacts).where("user_contacts.number = ?", '1234')
```

might be good